# g++ говорит включить библиотеку которая уже включена

Tags: c++, g++

Ошибки связанной с кривым названием нет

Сама ошибка - пытаюсь сделать список потоков, но 'поток' объявлен не был

Библиотека потоков включена

Часть кода которой я пытаюсь паралелить

```
int division = poolsize/threads;
thread threadList[threads]{};
for(int i = 0; i < threads-1; ++i){
    thread threadList[i] (...);
}
thread threadList[threads-1] (...);
```

Компилирую g++ -Wall -o name.exe code.cpp

Операционка - Windows 7 64bit

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверил, могу ли я вообще создавать потоки

```
#include <thread>
void nothing(){}
int main(){
std::thread a(nothing);}
```

Компилятор дает ошибку - std::thread не объявлен, добавьте #include thread.

скачал gcc с первого попавшегося сайта(https://programforyou.ru/poleznoe/kak-ustanovit-gcc-dlya-windows)(ftp://ftp.equation.com/gcc/gcc-9.2.0-64.exe)

На #include  компилятор не ругается

-std=c++11 ничего не поменяло

В самом файле thread все лежит под #if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS), это может как-то повлиять?

Comment: Ничего не видно, что за код, какая ошибка...

Comment: [mcve] в студию.

Comment: *"Часть кода"* - не подходит. Нужен кусок кода, который мы можем скормить компилятору и получить ту же ошибку.

Comment: Ваш компилятор C++11 совместимый? Попробуйте добавить флаг -std=c++11

Comment: Откуда вы скачали gcc?

Comment: Может у вас с кодировкой файла что-то не так? На `#include <thread>` компилятор не ругается?

Comment: *"скачал gcc с первого попавшегося сайта"* А зря. Скачайте MSYS2 и поставьте гцц оттуда.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat причем тут откуда человек скачал gcc?????

Comment: @Maggot Потому что версии/сборки gcc под винду бывают разного качества. Я не особо за этим слежу, но, кажется, оригинальный MinGW (который не w64) не поддерживает многопоточность. Сборка из MSYS2 - точно поддерживает.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - при установке любого mingw на окошки - всегда спросится posix thread или win ))) (любого - ну последние релизы года так за 2)

Comment: @Maggot Любого? MinGW-w64 спрашивает, да. MSYS2 не спрашивает. Про обычный MinGW не уверен.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat за сус сказать не могу - не пользовался, j,обрезанный mingw_win64 спросит, обычный должен спросить если у людей которые его релизят есть голова)

Answer (score 2):

Это нормальное поведение gcc. Необходимо указать соответствующий флаг компоновщику.

Есть man на  gcc -  [man_gcc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)

Вот выдержка которая Вас должна интересовать -

> -pthread
>   Add support for multithreading using the POSIX threads library. This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker. It does not affect the thread safety of object code produced by the compiler or that of libraries supplied with it. These are HP-UX specific flags.

Собирайте все с флагом **-pthread**

```
gcc -std=c++17 -pthread *бла бла бла*
```

или

```
gcc -std=c++17 MyProgram.c -o MyProgram -lpthread
```

Стандарт указывайте хоть 11!

**P.S. заинклюдить хэдер и линканкуть библиотеку - вообще разные вещи в принципе)**

Comment: *"нормальное поведение"* Хм, мой компилирует без флажка.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Какая ось, версия gcc?

Comment: Винда, msys2. А на убунте без флажка выдает другую ошибку, `undefined reference to ...`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat за винду пояснить не могу - ибо там не тру gcc, по убунте ошибка верная - компоновка с позиксной тред либой не прошла - вот и референса нет. Но какой gcc стоит под убунтой и msys - Вы утаиваете)

Comment: 9.2, 9.2.1, но вроде без разницы. :) Старые так же себя вели.

Comment: Добавление флага не помогло, 'gcc -v' показало, что 'thread model=win32', как я понял это значит, что потоки делать нельзя. Видимо надо было действительно переделать компилятор, но я обошелся скачиванием некой https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads

Comment: @user369070 возможно и такое. Просто поставьте самый свежий mingv. Этот флаг для позикс. Ибо это все же эмуляция gcc ну или трансляция в некоторых исполнениях. Почуем MSVS не используете ? Или если нужен gcc почему не Linux ?